# I built an iOS software to parse a website. But the website looks like xhtml. How does object-c parse it？

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing, xhtml

This is the website source code.
Can NSXMLParse parse xhtml? Or does it have other methods to parse?
Thank for any help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title>欢迎使用正方教务管理系统！请登录</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="gb2312">
        <meta content="all" name="robots">
        <meta name="author" content="作者信息">
    </HEAD>
    <body class="login_bg">
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="default2.aspx" id="form1">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="dDwtMTg3MTM5OTI5MTs7Pq8P3aN430wxnb8E8wpdnb1wOEq+" />

            <div class="login_main">
                <div class="login_logo">
                    <h2><img src="logo/logo_school.png"></h2>
```

Comment: Since xhtml is (or should be) valid XML, then yes, any XML parser should be able to parse the xhtml.

Comment: Despite the doctype, the sample you post doesn't show XHTML. So an XML parser will not be able to parse it. You should use an HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I parsed it as html.It is ok.